# AppleScript auto Email attachment save

Tags: mail.app, email, applescript

I am looking for an AppleScript, that simply uses an email defined by the "Mail Rules" and extracts the attachment to a specific folder. I found different codes, but they all didn’t do want I want. I don’t want the code to change the name or create a new folder. I just want him to extract the attachment from the Email and store it in a defined folder.

What I want to do is, when I get an email with a specific subject (which is always the same). The script should extract the attachment, move it to a folder on my Mac and then mark the email as unread and delete it.

I just want it to use the new email. I specified this with the "email-rule"s feature from Mail but Mail didn’t hand over the email so I ended up with the script running but no email.

Comment: Could you perhaps add an AppleScript that you found which could be adapted to suit?

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Something like this. But I found many more, unfortunately I am not good enough with applescript to know what to change. http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/automatically-save-mail-attachments-using-applescript.php